# Automatically inserting emails into SQL DB from text file

Tags: php, sql, database, insert

I have a plain text file, containing emails in the following format:

```
"Name Surname" <name.surname@exmaple.com>,  'Name2 Surname2" <name2.surname2@example.com>, ...
```

**Note:** there are two spaces between each name-email pair. The whole file is on a single line.

How could I, using PHP, extract the data (only the email is necessary, but the name would be nice too) and insert it in an SQL database (assuming `$dbc` as the SQL Connection Object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = file_get_contents('emails.txt');
$file = explode(',',$file);
foreach ($file as $recipient) {
    $recipient = explode('<',$recipient);
    $name = trim($recipient[0]);
    $name = str_replace("'",'',$name); // remove apostrophes
    $name = str_replace('"','',$name); // remove double quotes
    $email = str_replace('>','',$recipient[1]); // remove ">"
    echo $name . ' ----- ' . $email . '<br />';
}
```